# Force overwrite file

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using this in my generator

```
this.fs.copy(this.templatePath('index.html'),this.destinationPath('index.html') );
```

I want it to skip the overwrite confirmation everytime it finds a confilict (like force overwrite option)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not possible. Yeoman will always ask the user for confirmation before overwriting a file. This is a contract the tool takes with its users: it won't overwrite a file without their acknowledgement.

As a user, if you trust your generator, you can run it with the `--force` flag to automatically overwrite the conflicting files.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a must to do, you can still `force` overwriting files by using [fs.copyFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback), [fs.writeFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) or [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)() function from `fs`. both functions write data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists.

```
const yosay = require("yosay");

....

fs.writeFile(filePath, fileContent, 'utf8', err => yosay(err));
```

If you get error `File already exists`, you may need to set explicit `write` flag in the the third param to make it work:

```
fs.writeFile(filePath,fileContent,{encoding:'utf8',flag:'w'}, err => yosay(err));
```

OR

```
const fs = require('fs');

// destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('source.txt', 'destination.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
```